# Sphinx - autodata shows str.__doc__

Tags: python, string, exec, python-sphinx

I'm trying to document my python code with Sphinx, but I found a problem documenting some data instantiated with `exec`; I have a table with names and values that I need to instantiate.

So in my code I wrote something like:

```
my_vars = [{'name': 'var1', 'value': 'first'},
           {'name': 'var2', 'value': 'second'}]

for var in my_vars:
    exec("{var[name]} = '{var[value]}'".format(var=var))
```

The problem is with Sphinx: since I'd like to maintain just the source code I used `autodata`, the corrisponding lines from my `.rst` file are:

```
.. autodata:: mymodule.var1

.. autodata:: mymodule.var2
```

that when built gave me this:

```
mymodule.var1 = 'first'
    str(string[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str

    Create a new string object from the given encoded string.
    encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
    errors can be ‘strict’, ‘replace’ or ‘ignore’ and defaults to ‘strict’.

mymodule.var2 = 'second'
    str(string[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str

    Create a new string object from the given encoded string.
    encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
    errors can be ‘strict’, ‘replace’ or ‘ignore’ and defaults to ‘strict’.
```

I think autodata goes looking into `var1.__doc__` for a doc string and there found `str.__doc__` (that is the message shown before).

I really don't know what to do and I'm searching for a way of not showing that ugly doc string (but still maintaining `mymodule.var1 = 'first'`).

Or maybe even better a way to show my own doc, like: `var1 is this.` (but I wouldn't know where to put it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is this: document the variables in the module docstring instead of trying to get something usable from `autodata`.

mymodule.py:

```
""" 
This module is...

Module variables:

* var1: var1 doc
* var2: var2 doc
"""

my_vars = [{'name': 'var1', 'value': 'first'},
           {'name': 'var2', 'value': 'second'}]

for var in my_vars:
    exec("{var[name]} = '{var[value]}'".format(var=var))

...
...
```

You could also use [info fields](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html#info-field-lists):

```
"""

:var var1: var1 doc
:var var2: var2 doc
"""
```

This works, sort of, but the output is not as nicely formatted as info fields used to document class variables or function parameters.

---

Update: following up on comments about `str` subclassing. Does this work for you?

```
from collections import UserString   

my_vars = [{'name': 'var1', 'value': 'first', "doc": "var1 docstring"},
           {'name': 'var2', 'value': 'second', "doc": "var2 docstring"}]

for var in my_vars:
    code = """\
{0} = UserString('{1}')
{0}.__doc__ = '{2}'""".format(var["name"], var["value"], var["doc"])
    exec(code)
```

Comment: this seems nice, but do you think there could be a way to put the doc string into my_vars,   
maybe like: `{'name': 'var1', 'value': 'first', 'doc': 'var1 doc'}`  
and then extract that doc string?

Comment: I did fiddle a bit with some attempts at setting the `__doc__` attribute on the variables, but I could not get it to work. I got error messages about `__doc__` being read-only (because strings are immutable, I guess).

Comment: Do you think it might be a good idea to subclass str into exec to override `__doc__`? I just tried and it works for the documentation, but my `var` is not a `str` anymore (and since they're going to be intra-package constants I don't know if it's a good idea), what do you think?

Comment: Is the extra complication of subclassing `str` just in order to document some variables really worth the hassle? I'm inclined to say "no"; I don't think I could be bothered. Perhaps there is a use case, but I don't see it based on the information given so far.

Comment: yeah! it works good :) thank you very much and sorry for not being able to give you the +1, this was my first question and it seems I don't have enough reputation (but when I do I'll come back) :)

Answer (score 1):

I realized how can you fix it.
Write smth like this:

```
x = 55
"""
x is varibble lala
"""
```

Use automodule directive and Sphinx will make docs for you.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the case. The variables are not at module level, but stored as strings-pair `name: value` inside a dict (the reason for this is mainteinability and compatibility with an older design, anyway it's not a matter to discuss here). This mean that the variables are brough at module level with `exec` and this messes up the doc attribute read by sphinx. I hope to have cleared what exactly this issue is about.

Answer (score 0):

Given that in this case is hard to let `sphinx.ext.autodoc` generate the desired documentation string because:

- the code is evaluated through `exec`
- the values might not let you overwrite the docstring

have you considered hardcoding the documentation in the `rst` document itself?

```
.. data:: mymodule.var1

   var1 is this

.. data:: mymodule.var2

   var2 is that
```

Comment: yes, sure this is a way, but what i'd really like to have is write the doc string in the source conde and then find a way to get that into my rst